# jquery flot graph in dialog

Tags: php, jquery

Problem: Display jquery flot graph in dialog box

I have a page which displays a horizontal bar graph using flot and this is interactive.
When i click on any of the bars, it executes getJSON and with the variables passed, plots another graph in an external php page.
I'm trying to get the graph drawn in the external php page displayed in the jquery dialog box.

Ive been looking everywhere but i'm unable to figure out a solution. Any help is appreciated.

```
    $.getJSON("page2.php?"+data, function(mdata) {
        $('<div></div>').html(result).dialog({ 
        autoOpen: false, 
        modal: true, 
        title: 'Page Hits - Monthly', 
        width: 450, height: 300 
    }).dialog('open');
```

page 2 is where the graph is drawn and i want to display the graph in the current page inside a dialog box.

Comment: shouldn't you set mdata as the html?

Comment: Sorry, the result and mdata was used when i was debugging earlier. If I used html as function (html) what would i pass to the dialog box ?

Comment: I'm not sure if getJSON will return the graph drawn in an external page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe try `$.get` instead of `$.getJSON`

```
$.get('page2.php?'+data, function(response){
  $('<div></div>').html(response).dialog({ 
    autoOpen: true, 
    modal: true, 
    title: 'Page Hits - Monthly', 
    width: 450, height: 300 
  });
});
```

Comment: I tried, but the dialog box opens and its blank. I even tried printing the response in a div tag and it is blank as well. So i'm guessing I'm not getting the graph as response back.

Comment: are you sure `page2.php` gets loaded with the right path and parameters? Try to take a look at its status code and response w/ firebug or something similar.

Comment: When i open page2.php with the data parameter, the graph is drawn. So i'm assuming the page is working just fine.

Comment: Ok i managed to fix this. I was using the same variable names on page1 and page2 in the javascript and that was messing up the code. Its working great. Zillion thanks for your help ! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

you could just create a PHP class to contain your data, store your graph data in an instance of the class and then pass the object as a post data to your dialog or popup window.

Then could create a method to process the custom data and draw the graph accordingly.

Comment: I havent tried classes yet. Thanks for the response, ill use this as excuse to learn classes and implement it.